# How to make array like this?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to modify my array by using like `np.tile` other than using `for loop`.

```
a = np.array(range(1,50)).reshape(-1,1)
a_new = np.tile(a, (100,1))
print(a_new)
```

will print out

```
[[1]
[2]
[3]
...
[48]
[49]
[50]
]
```

There will be `100 of [1][2]...[49][50]`, right?
However, I want to make `a_new` like this below.

```
[[1]
[1]
[1]
...
[2]
[2]
[2]
...
[49]
[49]
[49]
...
[50]
[50]
[50]]
```

I want to create an array `a_new` as `100 of [1], 100 of [2], ... 100 of [50]`.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.repeat(a, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       ...,
       [49],
       [49],
       [49]])
```

Comment: Oh, there is np.repeat! Thank you so much!